# How to delete empty field?

Tags: pydantic

I have a BaseModel like this

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class TestModel(BaseModel):
    id: int
    names: str = None
```

While I validate some data like this

```
TestModel(id=123).dict()
```

I got result

> {'id': 123, 'name': None}

But what I expect is:

> {'id': 123}

Question:
Is there a method to delete empty field?  Thanks!

Comment: I found a solution. First, give the field a default value `None`. Then, use ```TestModel(id=123).dict(exclude_none=True)``` to exclude it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The correct way to do this is with

```
TestModel(id=123).dict(exclude_none=True)
```

If you need this everywhere, you can override `dict()` and change the default.

Comment: Is this supported as an option within `BaseModel.Config`? Would be nice to see this as a declarative option.

Answer (score 9):

You can also set it in the model's `Config` so you don't have to keep writing it down:

```py
class TestModel(BaseModel):
    id: int
    names: str = None

    class Config:
        fields = {'name': {'exclude': True}}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete keys from a dictionary with value "None" :

```py
result = {k: v for k, v in result.items() if v is not None }
```

Comment: But everywhere use the validator must have this operate, and it is not related to logical code. Is it possible to complete it in validator?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can perhaps add a root_validator:

```
@pydantic.root_validator(pre=False)
def check(cls, values):
    if values['some_key'] is None
        del values['some_key']
```